# Oblique asymptote polar equation

Tags: real-analysis, polar-coordinates

I have the polar equation $r(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}}$. I can see that it has an oblique asymptote for $\theta \rightarrow\pi/4+$, but what is it in Cartesian form ?

Comment: @Klosew do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Does [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D%281%2F%28theta-%28pi%2F4%29%29%29&x=0&y=0) help ?

Comment: I tried that already, but it does not give the asymptote

Comment: [This](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D%281%2F%28theta-%28pi%2F4%29%29%29+asymptote&x=0&y=0)

Comment: Ive got that already, I need the asymptote in cartesian

Comment: Woah ! I deleted my comment assuming it was wrong . Abel's answer matches mine .So I am sort of reposting it." I learnt it from [here](http://home.scarlet.be/math/polar.htm#Asymptotes) and got $r=1/(sin(\theta-\pi/4))$ in its polar form which gives $y=x+\sqrt{2}$ in its cartesian form. "

Answer (score 1):

the asymptote is parallel to the the line $y = x$ not necessarily $y = x.$  i will try to find the asymptote by looking for in the form $$y = x + a $$

in polar coordinates, the asymptote is $$r \sin \theta = r\cos \theta + a\to a=\frac{\sin \theta - \cos \theta}{\theta - \pi/4}=
\sqrt 2\frac{\sin (\theta - \pi/4)}{\theta - \pi/4} \rightarrow\sqrt 2 \text{ as } \theta \to \pi/4.$$

so the asymptote is $$y = x + \sqrt 2. $$

Comment: So $\theta=\pi/4$ gives the direction as mentioned [here](http://home.scarlet.be/math/polar.htm#Asymptotes) ?

Comment: You mean $\sin(\theta-\pi/4)$ I presume and not $\sin\theta-\pi/4$

Comment: @Klosew, yes, the direction is given by $\theta = \pi/4$

Answer (score 0):

Asymptote means $r\rightarrow\infty$. It gives immediately $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ in polar ie $y=x$ in cartesian gives the direction of the asymptote. See Abel's post for a complete answer.

Comment: I know that $\theta \rightarrow \pi/4+$, but the asymptote is not y=x

Comment: @JimmyP But $\theta = \pi/4 $ is $y=x$ in cartesian

Comment: @Klosew but you could see in wolfram that the oblique asymptote isnt y=x

Comment: @JimmyP Maybe the wolfram plot was not on the x-y axis but the r-$\theta$ axis hence it didnt look like the straight line.